# Log4Net Rollover failing on .Net Core Function

Tags: log4net

I've been using Log4Net (2.0.8) configured for RollingFileAppender for several years on Windows projects so it made sense to keep using when migrating to .Net Core functions on Azure.  After a few challenges getting it established I was happy to find it working relatively well.

But the thing about logs is you only tend to look at them when investigating an issue.  That's when I found the following issues:

1. When reaching the maximumFileSize, the log would start over BUT the existing log file was not saved with the appended _1, etc.  Thus my logs just had the end of the day.  I thought I resolved this issue by giving a very large size for the maximumFileSize, so it would never have to create the incremental file.
2. However, sometimes when the end of the day was reached a new file is created BUT the existing file is not getting renamed to the filename.date file representation.  Thus I lose the whole days log!

For anyone curious, here's what my config file looks like: 
`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<log4net>
  <appender name="TecsRollingFile" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
    <file value="d:\home\logs\CESAlertsFunction.log" />
    <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
      <conversionPattern value="%level %date - %message%newline" />
    </layout>
  </appender>
   <root>
    <level value="ALL" />
    <appender-ref ref="TecsRollingFile" />
  </root>
</log4net>`

I'm at the point where I'm going to have to look at a different logging tool, since I need to be able to research what's in the logs.  I thought I'd throw this out to the community to see if anyone else has seen these problems and has any suggestions.

I just saw this SO article [Log4net RollingFileAppender is Overwriting file and not appending number to end](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54579061/log4net-rollingfileappender-is-overwriting-file-and-not-appending-number-to-end) so will give it a shot.  I don't have that in any of my other configuration files, but am hoping it works here.

Thanks in advance...Steve

Answer (score 0):

Adding the maxSizeRollBackups parameter resolved this issue.